# Menu is not showing on Action Bar

Tags: android, menu, show

My question is a popular question and I read and tried out a lot of related posts, but I didn't realize the expected result, show menu. I haven't found a right solution for it.

My application is works perfectly on Android version 4.2.2. (version code 17) I tried out it on a Galaxy Duos phone.

I using Android version 7,0 (version code 24)
I tried with more variation of target SDK version, with 8,19, 24,25 and without target SDK specification.

Here are some relevant parts of

**-build.gradle**

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.mobile.apps.mnb"
        minSdkVersion 8
    }
}

**-AndroidManifest.xml**

android:minSdkVersion="8"

**-optionsmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exit">
    android:title="@string/menuitem_exit">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details">
    android:title="@string/menuitem_about">
</item>
</menu>
```

**-Main.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
            return true;
        case R.id.exit:
            Intent intentData = new Intent();
            intentData.putExtra("IS_EXIT", new Boolean(true));
            setResult(android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK, intentData);              
            finish();
            System.exit(1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a Fragment?

Comment: Not the Fragment I'm using Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem in enclosing of menu items:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exit"
    android:title="@string/menuitem_exit" />  //item not enclosed properly

<item android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    android:title="@string/menuitem_about" />
</menu>
```

Keep it simple:

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
In my opinion the "</item>" is enclosed it.

Comment: yes but you are adding `>` before the `android:title`

Comment: If I changed the minSdkVersion to 11 than the menu items are appear but the content of the main UI is not.

Comment: Agh yes it's true copy paste disease, inattention. The mindSdkVersion set to 11 is required for the settings "android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText""